# How to overcome Error when pip installing okta?

Tags: python, pip, okta, okta-api

I'm working with Python 3.8.9 and I need to use the Okta package. I try to install it as their documentation suggests: `pip install okta`, but I get this error:

```
...
Failed to build aiohttp yarl multidict frozenlist
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, yarl, multidict, frozenlist which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try upgrading pip then attempt installing again:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install okta
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes.